# How to show jQueryUI tooltip all the time?

Tags: jquery, tooltip, colorbox

Is it possible to show tooltip all the time, thus removing hover/mouseover?
I just want to remove the hover event and just show the tooltip.

```
$(function () {
    $(document).tooltip({
        content: function() {
            return $(this).attr('title');
        },

        position: {
            my: "center bottom-8",
            at: "center top",
            using: function(position, feedback) {
                $(this).css(position);
                $("<div>")
                .addClass("arrow")
                .addClass(feedback.vertical)
                .addClass(feedback.horizontal)
                .appendTo(this);
            }
        }
    });

    $.metadata.setType('attr', 'data');
    $('.viewMap').on('click', function() {
      var data = $(this).metadata();
      var e = data.href;
      var flID = data.floorID;
      var arID = data.areaID;
      var emID = data.employeeID;
      });
      colorbox(e);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add [the `show` property](https://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#option-show) to the object you are passing to `.tooltip();` and set it to `false`* like so:

```
$(document).tooltip({
    content: function() { /* ... */ },
    position: { /* ... */ },
    show: false // there you go
});
```

And then, you must use [the `enable` method](https://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#method-enable) of jQuery UI tooltip, like so:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(document).tooltip('enable');
});
```

And you'd be good to go for having your tooltip displayed all the time.

> <sup>* When set to false, no animation will be used and the tooltip will be shown immediately.</sup>